# Vanilla dedicated server, can I configure a list of bot names

Tags: team-fortress-2, hosting

I have a dedicated TF2 server set up for in-office breaks which our department uses to play together. We use `tf_bot_quota_mode fill` and tf_bot_quota 24` to make sure we have plenty of things to shoot and be shot by, even when only a few people are playing.

The bots have names picked randomly from a list. The list is enumerated on the [TF2 Wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Bots#AI_bot_names).

Is there a simple way of modifying this list of names that are randomly assigned to bots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Vanilla

In a vanilla server there is no way to edit bot names from a list as they are hardcoded into the game. The only way to change bot names in vanilla is to do this command:

> tf_bot_add [count] [class] [team] [difficulty] [name]

Read about this command [here.](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Bots#AI_bot_commands)

---

### Plugin

I have found [this plugin](http://gamma-level.com/teamfortress2/botnames) that allows you to edit a `botnames.txt` file to easily change the bot names.

Find it [here](http://gamma-level.com/teamfortress2/botnames), or on [github](https://github.com/agrif/botnames).

> **Quck Start**
>
> If you have to, build `botnames.smx`. Then, put `botnames.smx` into
>   your SourceMod plugins folder, and copy `botnames.txt` into
>   `addons/sourcemod/configs/`. Edit `botnames.txt` to your liking:
>   Comments start with `//` or `#`.
>
> [Source](https://github.com/agrif/botnames)

Comment: The plugin you mentioned looks promising, but doesn't include installation instructions. How do I take the .sf file they provide and get it working on my server? Sourcemod and metamod are already installed.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://gamma-level.com/teamfortress2/botnames)

Comment: The updated link doesn't have installation directions either.

Comment: I have edited the post, please have a look

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. Looking at the github page, I see this was the README file...now I feel dumb for missing that. :S